# Replacing H-style track lighting lamps with a different H-style brand

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety

The installation instructions for my new track lighting heads (lamps) say: "This fixture can only be used with Lithonia (brand) track". But I was hoping to use them on my currently installed track of a different brand. The track (Hampton Bay brand) is UL listed. Both lamps and tracks are H-style. Does the brand really have to match too?

Comment: To keep the UL listing, yes the brand has to match.  Although, If it works..........

Comment: True but sad same rule for circuit breakers.